# convert int array to binary array

Tags: arrays, matlab

Currently in matlab i have int array `a=[8 3 2 1];` i want to convert it to binary array with four bits each.

for the above int array i would get the following binary array a `binary=[1000 0011 0010 0001];`

I tried the code given below:

```
binary = dec2bin([8 3 2 1],4)
```

I got answer as :

```
1000
0011
0010
0001
```

It is a column matrix.
But I need a row matrix. `[1000 0011 0010 0001]`

can anyone help me????

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need the leading zeros, you can use:

```
binary = str2num(dec2bin([8 3 2 1],4))'
```

This will give you:

```
binary =

        1000          11          10           1
```

---

If you want the leading zeros, you can use:

```
binary = cellstr(dec2bin([8 3 2 1],4))'
```

This will give you:

```
binary = 

    '1000'    '0011'    '0010'    '0001'
```

---

**Edit:** To take the complement of each bit of the array, you can use:

```
cmp = cellstr(dec2bin(bitcmp([8 3 2 1],4),4))'
```

You will get:

```
cmp = 

    '0111'    '1100'    '1101'    '1110'
```

Comment: @lara As in method #1, you can get the binary number without leading zeros.

Comment: But i need that leading zeros because i need to take the complement of each bit in a number.That is, if it is 0011 , then it changes to 1100.So i need 4 bit representation.